# Confused in elementary CSS position and cascading rule application

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is position `fixed` coming from a css below mine. Now when I make its position `relative` in my CSS, according to cascading rules, the `fixed` positioning will be applied to div and then in my CSS if I do like:

```
#blah {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 20;
}
```

my CSS will be applied. However, I am confused that on changing position css attribute, will the div still be `fixed` and positioned `left: 20` relative to itself or `position: fixed` now has no role to play?

My use case being that I have a div which can be positioned `blah` but on addition of a class, I need to append a absolute div positioned according to my preferences inside it.

The methods I am thinking are either (i) add a class to original div and using that class, make it relative and then insert my absolute div or (ii) insert another div with position relative inside of original div and then insert the absolute div inside it.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where is your `position: fixed` declaration? If we don't see it there's no way we can know how cascading should be applied, if at all. All I can say is that a given element can only be either one of `position: relative` or `position: fixed` at any time.

Comment: `fixed` positions an element relative to the viewport. You can add an additional rule containing that additional class and it will take precedence over the original one (that with the `fixed` attribute).

Comment: @BoltClock thanks, I have a footer which needs to be scrollable and has a custom scrollbar. The custom scrollbar has class root which has `style= position:relative;top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;` and the scrollbar thumb inside .root has `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 5px;`. To put scrollbar inside footer, I appended a div with class root inside footer. But, I was wondering if instead of putting the div inside of footer, I can add the class root to footer and go my way. However, being new to the stuff, I got confused and seek help if its the right way to solve this case?

Comment: @zeroflagL thanks, have a look at my above response to know situation clearer. I was thinking about `<footer class='root'>` vs `<footer><div class='root'></div></footer>`

Comment: @gashu So the footer is fixed? But then it makes no sense to change that. If you want to put a scrollbar into your footer then, well, just do it. where else would you want to put it :) ?

Comment: @zeroflagL heh :) Actually the scrollbar has a class 'root' and all css is defined in respect to root. Just tell me whether `<footer class='root'>` can be used instead of `<footer><div class='root'></div></footer>` I wish to have minimal DOM manipulation in this case.

Comment: bah....ignore my last comment, opened eyes wide and re-read your suggestion and then understood :)